# can you detect a double-tap from javascript with angular-touch installed

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs

I'm trying to assign a gesture to "remove photo" on a touch device and a double-tap makes sense. Is there an angular friendly way to detect a `double-tap`, or even a `long-tap` from javascript? Angular-touch does not support it out of the box.

PS: I know I can use hammer.js but I'd rather not load another lib if I can avoid it. angular-carousel already loads angular-touch

Answer (score 1):

I poked through angular-touch.js and added this:

```
  longtapHandler = $parse(attr.ngLongtap),
```

this:

```
  /*
   * add longtap event
   */
  if (tapping && diff > (1 * TAP_DURATION) && dist < MOVE_TOLERANCE) {
    // Call preventGhostClick so the clickbuster will catch the corresponding click.
    preventGhostClick(x, y);

    // Blur the focused element (the button, probably) before firing the callback.
    // This doesn't work perfectly on Android Chrome, but seems to work elsewhere.
    // I couldn't get anything to work reliably on Android Chrome.
    if (tapElement) {
      tapElement.blur();
    }

    if (!angular.isDefined(attr.disabled) || attr.disabled === false) {
      element.triggerHandler('longtap', [event]);
    }
  }
```

and this

```
element.on('longtap', function(event, touchend) {
  scope.$apply(function() {
    longtapHandler(scope, {$event: (touchend || event)});
  });
});
```

it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no native way to do it, you could manually set it up using a timer.  Here's an implementation using javascript.  Same concept just convert it into your angular event.

```
clicks++;
if (clicks == 1) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(clicks == 1) {
            single_click_callback.call(self, event);
        } else {
            double_click_callback.call(self, event);
        }
    clicks = 0;
    }, timeout || 300);
}
```

[Code taken from this link](https://gist.github.com/ncr/399624)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ios-dblclick`, a directive I wrote to handle double click event on iOS Safari. It has no dependency and works like `ng-dblclick`.
It's available [here on Github](https://github.com/mrblackus/ios-dblclick).

Here's an example on to use

```
<div ios-dblclick="removePhoto()"></div>
```

And the directive

```
.directive('iosDblclick',
    function () {

        const DblClickInterval = 300; //milliseconds

        var firstClickTime;
        var waitingSecondClick = false;

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('click', function (e) {

                    if (!waitingSecondClick) {
                        firstClickTime = (new Date()).getTime();
                        waitingSecondClick = true;

                        setTimeout(function () {
                            waitingSecondClick = false;
                        }, DblClickInterval);
                    }
                    else {
                        waitingSecondClick = false;

                        var time = (new Date()).getTime();
                        if (time - firstClickTime < DblClickInterval) {
                            scope.$apply(attrs.iosDblclick);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```